# Code sample, any help debugging would be appreciated

Tags: python, pandas

i am getting an error with my code see 1st half of code below.    "File "C:\Users\29apo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Email_Search.py", line 83, in 
df_list_V2.iat[r, 4] = Email_Final
File "C:\Users\29apo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2118, in **setitem**
self.obj._set_value(*key, value=value, takeable=self._takeable)
File "C:\Users\29apo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3265, in _set_value
series._set_value(index, value, takeable=True)
File "C:\Users\29apo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1070, in _set_value
self._values[label] = value
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'mailto:ilan@uanalaw.com'

why?, any help would be appreciated.  I think I have installed all the depdencies."

---

````
```




    import csv
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
    import time
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
    import operator
    import pandas as pd
    from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
    
    
    #*************** Read the CSV file***********************
    #***************** Please make sure the CSV file is in same folder as the code/python path***************
    df_list =  pd.read_csv('sbey-1.csv')
    df_list_V2 =df_list
    #Getting the AI Column Values Column Number 34 in the given file
    df_domains = df_list[df_list.columns[34]]
    rows = df_list.shape[0]
    
    #Extracting Domains
    for r in range(0,rows):
        d = df_list.iloc[r][34]
        print(d)
        # Find position of 'first "."'
        Pos_1 = d.find('.',0)
        # Find position of second '.'
        Pos_2 = d.find('.', Pos_1+1)
        Domain_Act = d[Pos_1+1:Pos_2]
        # find .co/.com.in etc
        Pos_3 =d.find('/', Pos_2+1)
        if Pos_3 <=0:
            Pos_3 = len(d)
        Domain_Actual = d[Pos_1+1:Pos_3+1]
        #Search in Google
        webdriver = r"C:\Users\29apo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\chromedriver.exe"
        wd = Chrome(webdriver)
        links_search = []
        wd.get("https://google.co.in/search?q=" + Domain_Actual)
        time.sleep(10)
        # Get all the links fetched by google search in first page
        elems = wd.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
        for elem in elems:
            links_search.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
        # Enter number of pages to scrape to find the result:
        Numberofpagestoscrape = 1
        i = 1  
# Get all the links fetched by google next search pages
    for i in range(1,Numberofpagestoscrape):
        try:
            nextButton = wd.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
            nextButton.click()
            time.sleep(10)
            elems = wd.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
            for elem in elems:
                links_search.append(elem.get_attribute('href'))
        except:
            NoSuchElementException
    Emails_Found = []
    # Remove Noices in links
    for link in links_search:
        if link != None:
            if 'google' not in link:
                #print(link)
                try:
                    wd.get(link)
                    time.sleep(10)
                    try:
                        Elements_Emails = wd.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
                        for ele in Elements_Emails:
                            Emails_Found.append(ele.get_attribute('href'))
                    except:
                        NoSuchElementException
                except:
                    WebDriverException
    for e in Emails_Found:
        to_search_inlinks = "@" + Domain_Actual
        #print(to_search_inlinks)
        #print(str(e))
        if e != None:
            if str(to_search_inlinks).lower() in str(e).lower():
                if "?" in str(e):
                    Pos_4 = e.find('?',1)
                    Email_Final = e[0:Pos_4]
                    df_list_V2.iat[r, 4] = Email_Final
                    print(Email_Final)
                else:
                    print(e)
                    df_list_V2.iat[r, 4] = e



# un comment If required in new csv file
df_list_V2.to_csv('UpdatedWithEmailAddress.csv', header = False,index=False)
# un comment If required in same csv file
#df_list_V2.to_csv('sbey-1.csv', header = False,index=False)
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to explain what you are trying to do with your code and where that error occurs because your code says the error is in line 83, and there is no 83 lines in the code you provided.

Comment: What I am trying to do is give python the data in csv format of hundreds of website domain names.  Then it goes and checks search engines to determine if any email addresses are on any sites with that added domain name.  So microsoft.com then it looks for "@microsoft.com" to find fresh emails so I can contact these people by email.  Thank you Chris.  Any input is appreciated.